# Using Last-Modified and If-Modified-Since on a RESTful API

Tags: rest, http, last-modified, if-modified-since

I've been reading a few articles regarding setting headers for `Last-Modified` when a response is sent from a server. I understand the purpose for it, and how to set it, etc.

I also understand the incoming `If-Modified-Since` header and that it's asking has anything changed since this time. I understand how to retrieve the header and convert it to a timestamp, etc.

The aspect I'm struggling to get my head around is what I compare the modified since timestamp with. My understanding is that by using last modified I don't need my API to keep retrieving masses of data if it's still the same.

So, am I supposed to make a super lightweight call to the API's cache/database and just check for the last modification to whatever dataset is being requested?

Answer (score 2):

It's going to depend on the nature of the resource being requested, but I would think that you would want to take advantage of the web server's caching mechanism itself wherever possible. If you're using Apache, for instance, [mod_cache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_cache.html) should be the starting point for [your HTTP caching needs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/caching.html). I'd try and avoid manually implementing a full cache header implementation because you're likely to miss something, such as inadvertently introducing security risks to your application.

Answer (score 0):

> So, am I supposed to make a super lightweight call to the API's cache/database and just check for the last modification to whatever dataset is being requested?

Last-Modified/If-Modified-Since enables two optimizations:

1. **Conditionally skipping data retrieval on the server.** Examples:

- Query a PostgreSQL database for the timestamp. If necessary, perform additional queries to retrieve the data.
- Query a Redis cache. If necessary, query the MySQL database to retrieve the data.
- Propagate the value upstream to a S3 bucket, which will skip sending the object using the same criteria.

2. **Conditional skipping data transfer to the client.** I.e. 304 Not Modified.

(1) is heavily dependent on your architecture. (2) is available almost always.